# Odoo-14: How to add orderline in current POS order

Tags: odoo, odoo-14, pos

I need to append a "specific" product in current order's orderline on the the click on particular button, same functionality needs to be used i.e. when you click on any product and it gets added to orderline. With following line of code, unable to get order `id`:

```
this.env.pos.get_order()
```

I am unable to get in-process order `id` as it is not yet created in backend until its paid.

Comment: Maybe 'this' is not holding the correct context. In the outer context you can create var self = this and use var order = self.env.pos.get_order();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the order and add a new orderline you can use

```
var order = this.env.pos.get_order();
order.add_product(product, { quantity: 1, price: total_price });
```

Comment: yes, I did found it, but one issue if we add product with qty 1 then again click button and `add_product` gets called with new name and other attributes it overrides the existing line if at first qty != 1 then every time new product gets added, do you have any idea?